# How to open the door in Volkrund Keep

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-falskaar

How to open the door in Volkrund Keep? There is a lever besides the door, but it will not budge.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You follow Brother Arnand during the quest "[Dreams in Oblivion](https://tes-mods.fandom.com/wiki/Dreams_in_Oblivion)" and he activates the lever to let you in.

Comment: Can you specify; which quest?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a companion (mine is Serana) and try to open the door and lever and then just wait she will pull lever after a while and then open the door.

However, you must then run down the hallway quickly to make her follow you or she will pull the lever again and lock herself out.

Answer (score 1):

I use Lydia. I tell her I need her to do something, then hit <kbd>E</kbd> when pointing at the lever.  She will open the door using the lever, then you need to tell her to follow you.